# How do you create an AutoScaling IAM Role that restricts resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-emr, autoscaling

If I am creating the custom autoscaling policy and try to restrict only to the resources statrting with KJ, while creating EMR autoscaling status is fail, istead of that if I specify "*" then it work fine.. is there something I am missing in below policy code?

```
    resource "aws_iam_policy" "aut_policy" {
      name        = "test_autoscale_policy"
      #path        = "/"
      description = ""

      policy = <<EOF
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": [
                    "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                    "elasticmapreduce:ListInstanceGroups",
                    "elasticmapreduce:ModifyInstanceGroups"
                ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": [
                       "arn:aws:elasticmapreduce:*:*:kj*",
                       "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:kj*",
                       "arn:aws:events:*:*:kj*",
                       "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/kj*",
                       "arn:aws:cloudwatch:*:*:kj*"]
        }
      ]
    }
    EOF
    }
```

How do you create an AutoScaling IAM Role that restricts resources?

Comment: it would be helpful to add the error you are getting from terraform

Comment: There is no specific error.. only thing is on EMR, autoscaling status is Failed..rest EMR get launched successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The IAM Actions **elasticmapreduce:ListInstances** and **elasticmapreduce:ModifyInstanceGroups** both require `cluster*` Resource ARNs that look like this:

```
arn:${Partition}:elasticmapreduce:${Region}:${Account}:cluster/${ClusterId}
```

Providing a resource ARN pattern like the following will match no supported Resources and will NOT permit autoscaling to call those Elastic MapReduce APIs on your resources:

```
arn:aws:elasticmapreduce:*:*:kj*
```

The following `cluster*` Resource ARN should hopefully work:

```
arn:aws:elasticmapreduce:*:*:cluster/kj*
```

The IAM Action **cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms** requires an `alarm*` Resource ARN that looks like this:

```
arn:${Partition}:cloudwatch:${Region}:${Account}:alarm:${AlarmName}
```

Providing a resource ARN pattern like the following will match no supported Resources and will NOT permit autoscaling to call that CloudWatch API on your resources:

```
arn:aws:cloudwatch:*:*:kj*
```

The following `alarm*` Resource ARN should hopefully work:

```
arn:aws:cloudwatch:*:*:alarm:kj*
```

The following Resource ARNs are specified, but their are no Actions that match (harmless, but confusing):

```
"arn:aws:ec2:*:*:kj*",
"arn:aws:events:*:*:kj*",
"arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/kj*",
```

I *highly* recommend constraining the account in the ARNs. It's probably the most important constraint as any other account can create resources starting with **kj**.

You can read more about **Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon Elastic MapReduce** here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonelasticmapreduce.html

You can read more about **Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon CloudWatch** here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazoncloudwatch.html#amazoncloudwatch-alarm

Comment: Doesn't work.. still the status is Failed only.. for simplicity I removed kj just for check is the syntax working or not .. But no luck.. this is the updated code : "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticmapreduce:*:*:cluster/*",
                "arn:aws:cloudwatch:*:*:alarm:*"
            ]

Comment: Hmm. That's unfortunate. Sorry about that. Take a look in CloudTrail for recent denied API calls by the autoscaling service. It should have the ARNs of the affected resources.

Comment: On CloudTrail I am not finding any resources which are denied.. is there any different way we should find those denied API?

Comment: AWS Support is probably your best bet then. The underlying autoscaling failures should be showing up in CloudTrail normally.

Comment: As per this doc, Auto Scaling does not support specifying a resource ARN. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_applicationautoscaling.html

Comment: You haven't granted any Application Auto Scaling actions in your working policy so that restriction should not be relevant here.